# How to get the next matching item in row Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have a table with data and I'm struggling with getting the next match data in the row.
I've tried many options with no success and every time I'm getting the same solution.
can someone help/guide me to the better solution?
I've got pic that explain the problem:

[image]

Comment: Since your version of Excel does not have the `FILTER` function, I would suggest a VBA or Power Query solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 2 formulas solution use for **Excel 2010** and up

1] In "Output, ID" `A13`, formula copied across right to `C13` and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$6)/($D$2:$H$6=$K$1),ROW($A1))),"")
```

2] In "Output, Date" `D13`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($1:$1,RIGHT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$6)/1%+COLUMN(D:H)/(D$2:H$6=K$1),ROW(A1)),2)),"")
```

Or,

Using this single array (CSE) formula for **Excel 2019** and up

In "Output, ID" `A13`, formula copied across right to `D13` and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,IF($D$2:$H$6=$K$1,$A$2:$A$6&"</b><b>"&$B$2:$B$6&"</b><b>"&$C$2:$C$6&"</b><b>"&$D$1:$H$1,""))&"</b></a>","//b["&(ROW($A1)*4+COLUMN(A$1))-4&"]"),"")
```

confirm pressing with "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" to enter

[image]

Comment: wow! tnx.it was really helpful and solve my problem. I tried with Aggregate function and I didn't make it to the solution.